# I can't build and run my app without usb debugging

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk, usb-debugging

I'm requesting your help because I've made an app on Android studio, which works fine on my phone with usb debugging.
I tried to build the unsigned apk with gradle but it won't install and my phone says that "the package must be corrupted" when I try to install it. I also managed to install a debug version apk on my friend's phone, it installed but kept on crashing regularly and was unusable.
I probably have wrong settings in my project, but I'm new to this and don't really know what to do.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Goto **Build** Option->Choose **Build APK(S)** and then generate debug APK and that APK you can install in your device

Comment: Is it fine if it isn't a release apk ?

Comment: only generate debug apk

Comment: Done, that debug apk was successfully installed on my phone and seems to work. It crashes when my friend uses it though

Comment: You friend might be using a phone with versions above Lollipop.

Comment: I have Nougat, he has Marshmallow. It runs on his phone but is really slow a lot and then crashes

Comment: @Gogolplex Check crash issue if debug.apk generated successfully then it's not apk issue

Comment: Okay, well I don't know where it comes from then.. Two more friends tried it. Crashes on Marshmallow apparently but works fine on Nougat and Oreo